# Prolog member function list

Tags: prolog

Trying to figure out how to create a "member" function for a list. So far I've created this but I'm getting no where near to the correct answer.

---

```
spec([system001,hard_drive(50)]).
spec([system002,hard_drive(150)]).

list1(Component):-
    spec([Component,X|Y]).

which_system(Component, Component).

which_system(Component):-
    list1(Component),
    which_system(X, Component).
```

---

When I type in `which_system(system001).`
it works but when i put in `which_system(hard_drive(50)).`
it wont work at all... I dont know how to make it to find hard_drive(50).

I hope someone can help...

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't destroy your question once it has been answered. The whole point of this site is for older questions to help newer people with similar issues.

Comment: @user1726910: It would even be a courtesy to others to improve the formatting of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're doing it more complex than needed

```
which_system(Component, System) :-
  spec([System|Components]), member(Component, Components).
```

This works also if you'll have more components in a system, for instance `spec([system001, hard_drive(50), hard_drive(100)]).`.

```
?- which_system(hard_drive(50), S).
```

will instance S to system001.

Comment: Oh right typical of me doing it more complex. Thank you for solving the problem it definitively works like that now but is there a possible way in using just "which_system(hard_drive(50)"? than with the extra, S. 

Thanks by the way.

Comment: that way you just get true/false. A more appropriate name would be exists_system(hard_drive(50)). Anyway Prolog supports predicates with the same name and different num of arguments. Just drop what's not interesting... `which_system(Component) :- spec([_|Components]), member(Component, Components).`

Comment: Thanks, you've been helpful ! :)